# Boiler System heats one room more than all others

Tags: water, boiler, heat, zoned-heating

I have a two zone older natural gas boiler system. All rooms in the house get heat. One room on the second floor gets hotter than all others. Almost like all the heat is going to that room I don’t know why ? I do get a lot of noise from the boiler as well, lots of gurgling noises and pipes clanging. I recently replaced my hot water tank. I am thinking there is air in the lines but am not sure how to release that.

Comment: Is the delivery by baseboards? Do they have movable flaps, and have you closed those flaps in the room that is too hot? How to remove the air depends on how your system is built - there either will or will not be bleed valves (typically out of sight under baseboard radiator covers, often easier to find on cast iron radiators) at high points where you can bleed air, or it may be a more difficult arrangement - there may also be "auto-bleed" valves which may not be working right. If there is a lot of air you may also need to add water, and you might also need to find a leak and fix it.

Comment: Is it worse on sunny days vs cloudy? Does that room catch a lot of sun in the afternoon?

Comment: Yes the delivery is in baseboards, they do have moveable flaps, closing the flaps doesn’t make a difference. I don’t see anything under the cover of the baseboards, is that usually on the end of the pipes coming into the room? It’s not any different on sunny days vs cloudy days. Where would the auto bleed valves be if they aren’t at the baseboard themselves ?

Comment: see https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/37384/18078 for some tips on air bleeders.

Comment: You've got two different questions: 1) Why is one room hotter than the others? 2) Why is my boiler making lots of noise. If you'll take the [tour], you'll see that multiple questions don't work so well here, unless they're closely related. These are both related to your heating system, but that's about it - they'll most likely have totally different solutions. Please [edit] this down to one question, then ask a whole new one for the other question.

Comment: We really need more information on your system. What type of thermostatic control, is this the first room on that loop. Without more info on even the type of heat exchanger we can’t offer much help, if you don’t know take photos and add them we may notice something easy to do.